# iOS equivalent to macappstore://showUpdatesPage

Tags: ios, app-store

Is there an iOS-equivalent to macappstore://showUpdatesPage (linking to the Updates section of the App Store?
It seems like the simplest way to send customers off my App off to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send them to your app page in the AppStore, and they will have an update button:

```
NSString *iTunesLink = @"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/idYOUR-APP-ID?mt=8";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
```

Comment: My app has not yet 'been submitted to the AppStore, so I don't have an id yet, and I'd like to have this feature beginning with the first version. This also seems more complicated as soon as the app is available in different stores (countries).

Comment: Countries does not matter in this issue, as it will send you to the correct store. An you can retrieve your app id before submitting to app, in your itunes connect, after creating there a new app.